# Recursive Calculation of value with purrr from the tidyverse ecosystem

Tags: dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I need to do an iterative calculation in a dataframe. The dataframe (or tibble) looks
like this:

```
tribble(
    ~year, ~yield, ~capital, ~expected,
    1, 1.02, NA, 45900,
    2, 0.89, NA, 36401,
    3, 1.1, NA, 34541.1,
    4, .92, NA, 27177.81,
)
```

The calculation I want to perform is this: (capital - withdrawal) * yield.

'capital' is initialized with 50000 and 'withdrawal' is initialized with 5000. 'yield' is 5000 and stays constant.
For capital is the value from the row before is used to calculate the current row.

The column 'expected' is just for illustration of the value I expect from the calculation.

accumulate and accumulate2 from the purrr library seem the right choice to tackle the problem.

I played around for hours now with those function, however without a success. This is my latest try:

```
tribble(
    ~year, ~yield, ~capital, ~expected,
    1, 1.02, NA, 45900,
    2, 0.89, NA, 36401,
    3, 1.1, NA, 34541.1,
    4, .92, NA, 27177.81,
) %>%
    mutate(capital = capital %>% accumulate2(~ (.x - 5000) * .y, .y = yield, .init = 50000)) %>%
    unnest()
```

I appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that accumulate is including the initial value as the first data point, which you don't want. So we get everything from the second data point until the end

```
df <- tribble(
    ~year, ~yield, ~capital, ~expected,
    1, 1.02, NA, 45900,
    2, 0.89, NA, 36401,
    3, 1.1, NA, 34541.1,
    4, .92, NA, 27177.81,
)
initial_capital <- 50000
withdrawal <- 5000

mutate(df, capital = accumulate(yield, ~ (.x - withdrawal) * .y, .init = initial_capital)[2:(nrow(df)+1)])
```